# Перебор всех возможных комбинаций идущих подряд символов массива

Tags: c, рекурсия, перебор

Есть одномерный массив, состоящий из символов (римских цифр). Необходимо создать массив всех возможных комбинаций идущих подряд символов, например:

```
 IVI
-I+V+I
-IV+I
-I+VI
-IVI
```

Пытаюсь решить это с помощью рекурсии, смог написать алгоритм соединяющий первые два элемента `IIIVIII -> II+I+V+I+I+I`, но не могу понять как двигаться дальше.

```
char ***variants (char **tmp, int current_position, int width, int len)
{
char ***result = malloc(50 * sizeof(char**));
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    result[i] = calloc(50, sizeof(char*));
    for (int j = 0; j < 50; j++)
        result[i][j] = calloc(50, sizeof(char));
}
char symbol[width];
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
        symbol[i] = tmp[i][k];

int length = len - 1;
char **arr = malloc(length * sizeof(char*));
for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
{
if (j == current_position)
    arr[j] = calloc(width, sizeof(char));
else
    arr[j] = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
}
arr = tmp;

for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    arr[current_position][i] = symbol[i];

for (int i = current_position + 1; i < length-1; i++)
    arr[i][0] = tmp[i+1][0];

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    result[0][i] = arr[i];

return result;
}
```

Массив трёхмерный, потому что на данный момент мне так удобнее записывать результаты, каждая римская цифра комбинации в своей ячейке. Но в итоге, наверное, это должен быть массив.

Comment: Тег [рекурсия] говорит о том, что вам обязательно нужна рекурсивная реализация?

Comment: Нет, необязательно, но как я понял, в данном случае рекурсия - наиболее оптимальное решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны все возможные способы разрезать строку на подстроки, т.е. вставить разделители (`+`) между символами. Для строки длины `N` у вас есть `N-1` позиция для разделителей. Все варианты вставки разделителей - это все возможные подмножества множества размера `N-1`.

Так что все, что вам нужно сделать - это сгенерировать все возможные подмножества такого множества. Генерация всех таких подмножеств - это ни что иное как итерация через все целые числа от 0 до 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1. Позиции единичных битов в двоичном представлении каждого числа - это и есть элементы очередного подмножества.

Если бы мы заранее знали, что величина `N` не превосходит, скажем, 64, то такую итерацию можно было бы реализовать буквально на основе N-битного целого типа

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  const char str[] = "IIIVIII";
  size_t N = sizeof str - 1;

  printf("%s\n", str);

  for (unsigned long long subset = 0; subset < (1u << N - 1); ++subset)
  {
    printf("-");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
       printf("%c%s", str[i], ((subset >> i) & 1) != 0 ? "+" : "");
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

(Перенаправить результат в массив - дело техники.)

Существуют и другие алгоритмы генерации всех возможных подмноженств множества, не завязанные на максимальную разрядность целочисленного типа платформы, в т.ч. элементарные рекурсивные, но, учитывая как быстро растет размер результата с ростом `N`, можно предполагать, что о `N > 64` (или даже об `N > 32`) речи идти не будет.